# Transform a Product Stock table into Invoice-like table automatically (generating Invoice)

Tags: google-sheets, finance

apologies for such a bad title. First time creating thread here.

So i have this master table that includes columns:

- SKU
- Price per-item
- Opening Stocks
- Closing Stocks
- [and every **Customers Name**]

For the rows of **Customers Name**'s columns, it will contain the quantity of the stuff they're ordering.

*Here are the picture of the table:
[Master Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np8b8.png)*

*Here are the links of the Google Sheets: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NDnJrSqM4OkG03r7P2lScafOZBzxs9nV4Nluqmv0YiU/edit?usp=sharing*

The main goal of these problem is to **create invoice for each one of the Customers Name**.

*Here are the image of the invoice that i created manually:*
[Invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHCDO.png) *(also included on the Google sheets link above)*

I'm expecting to have a formula that could:

1. Generate the invoice automatically by double clicking the column of the **Recap**'s sheets [if possible :D]
2. Generate the SKU, Quantity, Price/Item, Total in the Invoice automatically as soon as i put the Customer Name on the Invoice field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one approach for your `point 2`. Change the name in `B4_Cell` to test it out:*

```js
=let(Σ,indirect("Recap!A1:"&rows(Recap!A:A)),Λ,choosecols(Σ,xmatch(B4,chooserows(Σ,1))),
     sort(filter({Recap!A:A,Λ,Recap!B:B,Λ*Recap!B:B},--Λ)))
```

- *within the `Invoice` tab you seem to have `~18 blank rows` between `headers`(**row_13**) and `SUBTOTAL` (**row_32**); so in a scenario where the formula data is more than 18 rows it will end up throwing an error*

[image]

Comment: OMG! That was a very fast response! Thank you so much. 

But I have a new question, if I add a blank row (for 'note' purposes) on the top of the master table (so the header of the master table will start on ROW 2), do i need to change any part of the formula?

Comment: Within the above formula you've to *ONLY* change this part of the formula `chooserows(Σ,1)` to `chooserows(Σ,2)` (since now header(s) are in second row)

Comment: Yes it works like a charm again. Thanks. But i have another issue. If i add a number of total qty ordered by each name on the 'note' i mentioned above, it will shown as well on the invoice. (if you get confused, i already modify the sheet above to show the error)

Comment: right now the only filter condition is `--Λ` (pull all numbers from Angeline Column→ so 14 value is also pulled). Add extra condition to the filter such as ***SKU_column not equal to blanks*** (`Recap!A:A<>""`)

Comment: Its already 7 days and i still use the solution you gave above. Thank you so so much. I hope i can learn more about spreadsheets from you. Thanks, mate!

Comment: Hi mate, hope you're doing great. So i just have a new request from my partner. Is it possible if i could get the Brand and Type as well? do you mind to share the updated formula?